# How to pass an option in to the frisby test through command line

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, frisby.js

I have to write some test base on a REST API. The end point may change each time running test suits.

Is it possible to pass end point option at command line. For example

```
jasmine-node --endpoint http://localhost:8080 test-folder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a way. Jasmin add a command line option to pass parameter as follow:

```
jasmine-node --config <name> <value>
```

for example:

```
jasmine-node --config endpoint http://localhost:9091 digidoki
```

Configs are accessible throw the following var:

```
process.env['endpoint']
```